# Could not load a dll although it is in bin and in gac

Tags: assemblies, gac, bin

In our web site project we need to reference the assembly System.Data.DataSetExtensions, 4.0.0.0. So we added a reference to it in the webconfig, but we are getting the following error on build:

error CS0012: The type 'System.Data.TypedTableBase`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

We added the dll version 4.0.0.0 in the bin folder of the site just in case.

At first in gac there was only version 3.5.0.0 of this dll, but we installed the 4.0.0.0 version via gacutil.exe. Now when we check with "gacutil.exe /l" the correct assembly version (4.0.0.0) appears to be loaded in gac, but we can not see it in the windows explorer in windows/assembly folder (there is only version 3.5.0.0). And we are still getting the same error.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: also in Process Monitor there is an entry from aspnet_wp.exe saying NO SUCH FILE for "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.INI". Could this be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your web project set to use the #4 .NET Framework?

Comment: but in webconfig there was not targetFramework="4.0".. when we added this, the problem disappeared. Seems that the defult version is "3.5" and it is used when not specified. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly question but, have you added a reference to the System.Data.DataSetExtensions to you web site's project references?
If not right-click on the website project, select properties from the context menu and then on the project properties page select the references tab.  Now click add reference and you should be able to figure it out from there.

Comment: yep, I've added it absolutely the same way - right click and Add reference

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.config`,set `targetFramework="4.0"`.